# jQuery UI DatePicker: Exclude days + dates

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

After browsing a lot of topics over here and trying different approches I still have problems with disabling days and dates in the jQuery UI DatePicker.

I tried creating 2 arrays which I check in the beforeDayShow option, but what ever I try, none of the days return unavailable in the calendar.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Disable Arrays
    var disableDays = [0,1,6], //su, mo, sa
        disableDates = ["22-02-2019", "24-02-2019"] //dd-mm-yy

    //Create DatePicker
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeDayShow: function(date){

            var day = date.getDay(),
                dmy = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);

            //Disable day
            if (disableDays.indexOf(day) != -1){
                return [false]; 

            //Disable date
            } else if (disableDates.indexOf(dmy) != -1){
                return [false];

            //Enable date
            } else {
                return [true];
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, i had made a "stupid" mistake.
I called the datepicker option "before**Day**Show" instead of "beforeShow**Day**"

It's working now